# OS X sigaction incorrectly setting sa_mask

Tags: c, macos, language-lawyer, sigprocmask, sigaction

On a macbook (OSX 10.9.5 (13F34)) the following simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

static void nop(int unused) { }

int
main(void) {
    struct sigaction sa, osa;
    sigset_t mask;

    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    printf("Errno after sigempty sa_mask: %d\n", errno);
    sigemptyset(&osa.sa_mask);
    printf("Errno after sigempty oldsa_mask: %d\n", errno);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sa.sa_handler = nop;

    sigprocmask(0, NULL, &mask);
    printf("Errno after sigprocmask mask: %d\n", errno);
    printf("%d\n", sigismember(&mask, SIGALRM));

    sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, &osa);
    printf("Errno after sigaction sa osa: %d\n", errno);
    printf("%d\n", sigismember(&osa.sa_mask, SIGALRM));
    printf("%d\n", sigismember(&sa.sa_mask, SIGALRM));

    return 0;
}
```

Mysteriously prints:

```
Errno after sigempty sa_mask: 0
Errno after sigempty oldsa_mask: 0
Errno after sigprocmask mask: 0
0
Errno after sigaction sa osa: 0
1
0
```

I would expect that the `sa_mask` member of `osa` to match `mask` as given by `sigprocmask`.

Does POSIX specify any requirements for this field? The only mention of it in the manpages is with regard to unblockable signals like `SIGKILL`, where that value is unspecified.

On linux, this program prints:

```
Errno after sigempty sa_mask: 0
Errno after sigempty oldsa_mask: 0
Errno after sigprocmask mask: 0
0
Errno after sigaction sa osa: 0
0
0
```

as expected.

The gcc version is:

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darw
```

The binary is linked against:

```
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

Comment: What's the library (and version) you are using on OS X? Does `errno` say anything after each of `sig*` calls?

Comment: @BlueMoon updated the question to answer your question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I would expect that the `sa_mask` member of `osa` to match `mask` as given by `sigprocmask`.

Your expectation is incorrect.

Here's a link to [the current (as of this writing) official POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/nfindex.html).  Bookmark it!

[Here is what that documentation says about `sa_mask`:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html)

> Additional set of signals to be blocked during execution of signal-catching function.

There is no reason to expect `osa.sa_mask` to match `mask`.  Your `mask` is the **current** signal mask.  Your `osa.sa_mask` is an **additional** signal mask that would have been applied during a call to `osa.sa_handler` to handle a `SIGALRM`.

In your test case, `osa.sa_handler` is `SIG_DFL`, so the contents of `osa.sa_mask` is irrelevant.  As far as I know (after a brief search), POSIX says nothing about what `osa.sa_mask` should be when, as in your test case, the process hasn't set an action for the signal since the most recent `exec`.

Furthermore, when the system calls an installed `SIGALRM` handler, it includes `SIGALRM` in the signal mask automatically (unless you passed `SA_NODEFER` or `SA_RESETHAND` when you installed the handler).  Quoting the documentation linked above:

> When a signal is caught by a signal-catching function installed by `sigaction()`, a new signal mask is calculated and installed for the duration of the signal-catching function (or until a call to either `sigprocmask()` or `sigsuspend()` is made). This mask is formed by taking the union of the current signal mask and the value of the `sa_mask` for the signal being delivered, and unless `SA_NODEFER` or `SA_RESETHAND` is set, then including the signal being delivered.

Thus it's irrelevant whether `sa_mask` includes `SIGALRM` if `sa_flags` is 0.  The fact that Linux doesn't include it and OS X does makes no difference to the handling of the signal.

Note too that it's not clear (to me) that it's legal to pass 0 (instead of one of the defined constants) for the `how` argument of `sigprocmask`, even when the `set` argument is null.  But I found that changing it to `SIG_BLOCK` made no difference.

Comment: This is I believe the correct answer. If we had a copy of 10.9.5's `libSystemB.dylib` or better, its source code, we'd probably find that as a courtesy it sets that bit in the sigset.

Comment: Agreed. Great answer!